# How to use multiple azure functions (app services) apps under one API domain?

Tags: azure, azure-functions

Can we deploy multiple azure function(app services) apps under one single API domain?

Comment: You have multiple options: API management (https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/api-management/), Azure functions also has Proxy capabilites: https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/azure-functions/functions-proxies

Comment: Azure function Proxies solved my problem...Thanks

Comment: Other users marked your question for low quality and need for improvement. I re-worded/formatted your input to make it easier to read/understand. Please review my changes to ensure they reflect your intentions. Feel free to drop me a comment in case you have further questions or feedback for me.

Comment: Also note that when you use Proxy for a function then the Proxy is considered as one function along with your original function. So from billing perspective it will be considered as two functions.